# Could you actually make a green space program?

Tags: economy, space-travel, energy, climate-change

Is it plausible to build and maintain a space program without adding to climate change?

While obviously there are larger problems in the near term with respect to climate change, I'm thinking about a slightly longer term context with something like [solarpunk](https://solarpunkanarchists.com/2016/05/27/what-is-solarpunk/). If we could reasonably have clean energy dominate(and I understand that is a big if), could we still keep a space program going?

I actually think the real problem might be economics. Assuming an eco-energy future, this implies that there would probably be a lower overall standard of living than we currently see in the US, which means there would be less resources to spend on something like a space program.

Comment: *"There would probably be a lower overall standard of living than we currently see in the US":* oh, that is perfectly fine. A standard of living just a little lower than what they have now in Morris of Minnesota would be a *massive* improvement for just about all the rest of the world. India and Russia have very successful space programs right now; increasing their quality of life to Minnesotan levels will do wonders. (And you are wrong. Mankind has never ever voluntarily chosen to live worse. We will switch to clean energy, whatever that is, only when switching will make our lives *better*.)

Comment: Re "lower overall standard of living", who is setting the standard?  By my standards, the typical American or European living in an urban area has a pretty miserable quality of life, some of which - e.g. urban air pollution - is a consequence of not being "green".

Comment: Only if you measure "standard of living" by monster truck rallies and rolling coal... yes, those poor city folk... being able to walk to actual opera and 3 different shops that sell just cheese.   Can we aid them somehow? Maybe force them to drive to the Walmart/cineplex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## We could do it tomorrow if we wanted to

We don't because it's cheaper to do things wastefully than green.

Now it's usually cheaper not because being green is implicitly more expensive, but because of [subsidies for oil and gas companies](https://www.eesi.org/papers/view/fact-sheet-fossil-fuel-subsidies-a-closer-look-at-tax-breaks-and-societal-costs), which run into the billions of USD per year, and that they're more established and have economies of scale. If the government decides to quit oil and gas and go green, the space program could survive and, after retooling, thrive even.

The biggest cost will be in 2 areas: manufacturing space craft, and getting those space craft to orbit. Everything else I'm assuming can be covered by "put some solar panels on the roof" or "buy local" level of greenness, same as any other office or government department.

#### Making space craft green

Steel and Aluminium are very energy intensive to make, but that energy can come from a green source, Eg [Germany is making green aluminium](https://reneweconomy.com.au/germanys-cheap-green-energy-keeps-aluminium-sector-healthy-58772/), or be offset by [carbon credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_credit). Also a focus on the re-use of ships (eg SpaceX's auto landing rockets) helps spread this environmental cost over the life of the rocket.

Many parts like plastic on the rockets are theoretically recyclable, or derivable from a green source, just it's not ecconomically viable to do so. When your government starts limiting the amount of oil which can be extracted to the point that prices of oil-derived products start to rise, we'll switch to green substitutes as soon as they become cheaper. PLA plastic is a pretty good example, it's common for entry-level 3D printing, that's [derived from corn](https://phys.org/news/2017-12-truth-bioplastics.html). Any exceptions (rare metals in computers, for example) can be covered with carbon credits.

#### Fuelling them greenly

You just need a lot of energy to get to orbit, that energy needs to come from somewhere, but where that comes from can be green.

How much fuel is needed to launch a rocket varies between designs, and I can't find consistent figures (and they're in freedom units rather than metric), but [this link](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/about/star/et_11.html) says 390 kilogallons of H2 and 145kilogallons of o2 in the external tank. Factoring in the shuttle internal fuel tanks hold fuel too, and the effect of the solid fuel boosters helping at the start, I'm guessing 500:200kilogallons of liquid hydrogen/oxygen should do the trick to get a decent sized rocket to LEO.

- 500 kgallon liquid h2 weighs 130 metric tonnes. (http://www.uigi.com/h2_conv.html)
- 200 kgallon liquid o2 weighs 860 metric tonnes. (http://www.uigi.com/o2_conv.html)

To produce 1kg of hydrogen by electrolysis costs [about 50kWh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_economy#Electrolysis_of_water), and you get the oxygen included it that. Excluding pressurisation and refrigeration costs, you're looking at 6.500TWh of energy per space launch.

The emissions put out by burning liquid oxygen and liquid hydrogen is - water vapour. It's the ultimate green fuel!

#### So how often can we launch?

Current solar production (as of 2018) in the USA is [96.1TWh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_power_in_the_United_States). Using only existing solar installations in the USA, you could do 14 launches a year.

If the solar output of china (204,700MW) was channeled entirely into fuel production for space craft launches, they could launch an equivalent rocket every 31.8 hours of direct sunlight. In summer the Chinese could maintain 3 launches per week entirely on green fuel, on their existing solar networks. (And 2 per week in winter)

The entire planet has a green energy production output of [2.3TW (combining hydro, solar, and wind)](https://www.irena.org/newsroom/pressreleases/2019/Apr/Renewable-Energy-Now-Accounts-for-a-Third-of-Global-Power-Capacity) If the world unites, we could launch a rocket on green power every 3 hours of full power generation.

Comment: ... And Australia could do 5 launches a year.

Comment: Why do you need hydrogen produced by (inefficient) electrolysis?  SpaceX has their Raptor engines burning methane https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Raptor which can be produced from your local sewage plant.  Or RP-1 is basically kerosene, which isn't all that far from biodiesel.  And you should also include geothermal and nuclear in that green energy total.

Comment: ... in which case my maths is an upper bound. My googling suggested mass production of methane needed electrolysis as a first step. If there's opportunity Methane then sure use that first, but I get the impression there isn't enough for bulk space launch.

Comment: Also geothermal is included in that number. I've heard good arguments for nuclear described as both a fossil fuel (it's non renewable) and green energy (hey no CO2!) - to guess an upper bound, I'm not including it. If you want to include it, just assume that it's even easier.

Comment: Its my understanding that the oil industry is not unique in getting government subsidies.  In the USA, in 2020, you can get a substantial tax credit for installing solar panels,  buying a plug-in type electric car, installing an energy efficient roof material, etc.

Comment: @Ash: But the reason you don't have a lot of green methane production is because it's so cheap as a fossil fuel, so the only places it gets produced are those, like sewage plants & manure digesters, where it's essentially a byproduct of something else.

Comment: Simply one of the many things that an appropriately priced carbon tax would fix rather quickly. Also I think that SpaceX is already looking intently at green methane production because they will need synthetic methane production on Mars. Musk has talked about this and it is brought up a lot on the SpaceX forums. Really just a matter of pricing and priorities.

Answer (score 2):

Many rockets are hydrogen fuelled today because it has a great energy to weight ratio. A great example is the Ariane rocket, which works on hydrogen since the beginning.

If we stop extracting it from natural gas and start making it from water with solar or wind generated electrical energy, we're there.

Estimates based on today's solar power production are not good: There are large, no, huge desert areas available today for solar which are not yet used. Once hydrogen production takes off, former oil states will use their deserts for energy production.

Answer (score 2):

A handful of reusable launches on greenly-produced spacecraft is nice, but let's look a little further forward, to an alternative.

If technology advances in some other areas, especially things like lasers and magnetic levitation, a whole bunch of non-rocket spacelaunch opportunities open themselves up for getting things into orbit without burning very much fuel at all. A small (compared to the sum of modern activities) initial carbon-intensive investment would let you build something like a laser-thermal launch system or a Lofstrom loop, which could be powered by renewable sources on the ground and don't entail any greenhouse gases spilling into the air.

Once your first set of infrastructure is up, there will inevitably be some environmental cost in mining resources from Earth to put things permanently in space. (Reusable surface-to-orbit vehicles are only part of the picture; you can't exactly bring a Mars colony building back to Earth to recycle it, so that mass is gone forever.) Thus, the immediate priority if Earth pollution is shunned will be to establish self-sustaining space colonies and extract resources from the Moon, asteroids, and so on instead.

Drop some space elevator cables to the surface once you've got all that set up (and technology's presumably progressed another few hundred years), and voila, GHG-free human exodus from Earth becomes fully possible for the masses. Feel free to turn the planet into a wildlife preserve or something.